Anti-pattern? Double header and exposed implementation detail
Consider that I've implemented SHA-256 hashing in C as incrementally updated IUF (init-update-finalize) working context and 3 subroutines. To use it in free-standing environment, or to efficiently use it in multi-threaded applications where mutex locking is expensive (e.g. due to lack of CPU instructions such as CAS/LckXchge), users may want to avoid heap allocation using malloc or calloc, etc. and declare the working context on the stack using a structure type I've provided in the header.
With such setup, I'll have to either use 2 headers - 1 for the user to include and provide only opaque definition, 1 for implementation with the implmentation details, or expose the implementation details of the working context in the header. Q Doesn't the former make it harder to maintain the code? and doesn't the latter break the abstraction?
Side note: C++ appear to have a similar problem where even private members need to be declared in the class header.
Please ignore the free-standing and mutex locking premise - they are only examples of why developer may choose to declare working context on the stack. Any reason may be substituted and the problem remains the same - as that in the title of this Q.

Using opaque definition doesn't make it harder to maintain the code. As long as you really have opaque structs, with no data, and you pass pointers around. That's a standard technique.

@freakish Sure, but I wonder what development strategy one can use to make it easier to make structure size (and alignment) consistent between implementation header and user header.

What do you mean? Opaque struct doesn't have neither size nor alignement.

I mean to be able to declare them as lexical variables, like pthread_t, pthread_mutex_t, etc.

I still don't understand. You declare struct my_wrapper; in header file. In some C file you actually define its fields (say pthread_t or pthread_mutext_t, etc.), and then you use my_wrapper* in public API. There is no size and alignement in header, it is only struct declaration, not definition.

pthread_t and many other types in POSIX thread are complete types. The standard permits usage such as pthread_mutex_t locallock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; and pthread_t tid = pthread_self();

How is that relevant? Define struct my_wrapper { pthread_t my_thread; } in C file. In the header it still is opaque struct my_wrapper;. Yes, you need to implement full abstraction layer for that to work.

@freakish I'm defining my own types! Are you capable of understanding that lexical variables in C must be complete types? If I were to declare a variable with an opaque type, it must have a compile-time size! And merely declare struct my_wrapper; in the header doesn't define the size of the type!

No, you are allowed to pass pointers to incomplete types. That's literally why opaque structs work and are useful.

@freakish I'm aware. I'm just wanting to learn from someone who has had experience maintaining 2 headers. (exposing implementation detail is straightforward already).

@freakish the question requests a way to allocate incomplete struct on stack. Passing pointers around is not enough for that, as stack is rolled back once hypothetical allocator returns.

This question is an architectural generalization of Allocate incomplete type on stack and Opaque types allocatable on stack in C

@Basilevs not "incomplete", only opaque. The only sense it may be incomplete is that it has no externally exposed/manipulatable component.

@DannyNiu all types without a complete declaration are incomplete. And as declaration is absent in compilation unit for your opaque type it is incomplete. Other compilation units and linking procedures are irrelevant for the term.

@Basilevs you just define an API that accepts an allocator. That's all. This is especially simple in C which allows VLA.

@freakish how would such allocator work without knowing the size of the area beforehand? As I see it, alloca() would not work.

@Basilevs fair enough. I suppose size can be exposed by the API then. In which case we don't need an allocator, but we can initialize on raw pointer instead. Alignement does not have to be exposed: just overallocate and align manually. Unless it is too costly to potentially waste few bytes, in which case should be exposed as well.

@DannyNiu is concurrent processing of different data sources required? If we are talking embedded (where this is not a concern), a statically preallocated hidden context would work. We can return an error if embedded API is used concurrently in non-embedded context.

@Basilevs How developer layout their memory is not my concern. I'm mostly interested in technique that maintains 2 headers consistently.

@DannyNiu when no concurrency is required, you do not need a second header.

@Basilevs Even when no concurrency is required, a second context may be needed in a nested function call.

@DannyNiu That's a concurrency by definition. Did you think parallelism? Yes, neither parallelism nor concurrency are allowed.

@Basilevs Then I guess I'm seeking to make a thread-safe implementation without exposing the implementation detail in the user header.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

alignment doesn't need special consideration sizeof(struct privately_defined) will handle that automagically.

Sorry about the distraction in the premise of the question.
For the proprietary software developers that have serious need to make data structrues opaque, they could have these options in their workflow:

Make implementation headers prerequisites of user headers in some make-based build system, so as to ensure the user header is up-to-date. The size (and alignment) of the data structures are reported from the implementation headers, and written to user header as part of the build process of the user header target.

Separately or as an addition, use (static) assertions to grab the attention of the developer whenever inconsistency occurs.


While nowadays we have FOSS library for pretty much everything, proprietary SDKs (with implementation details stripped from their header files) still find their place in IP-critical sectors, such as multi-media equipments industry.

I think this will often work,  still I guess one has to be careful with this approach when the build process runs on a different hardware than the final program.

@DocBrown the sizes and offsetas are stored in code. How would hardware affect anything besides alignment?

@Basilevs:step 1 requires some generator tool which will be executed on the build platform and reports sizes and alignment on that platform. If the user of the library compiles and runs the code then on a platform with different size and alignment, this may cause issues.

@DocBrown the generator is run as part of the build, so sizes are recomputed for each platform.

@Basilevs: there are 2 builds: the OP's build which creates the user header, and the user's build, maybe on a different platform. The OP's build includes running the generator on the platform they use for their build, which is not necessarily the target platform.

Meh, if platforms are mismatched, all bets are off. Also, it is possible to include arch guards in the header.

@Basilevs FYI, I use qemu-user to test my programs on different architectures, I could do the same to generate those sizes and alignments.

What “multi-threading” are you using that makes malloc inefficient? Typically allocation and deallocation on the same thread has zero overhead and is a lot easier to handle than stack allocation.
Just hide the structure, add two functions alloc_sha_context and free_sha_context, and it is totally opaque.

That's a hypothetical situation that's immaterial for the purpose of this question. I've edited accordingly.

And suddenly you added mutexes. Even more reason to avoid stack allocation and use an allocator / deal locator in your code instead.

this seems kind of limiting,  what if  the user  doesn't  want to use your chosen allocator.

@Jasen If he doesn’t want to use the allocator that I wrote which is tested, working and efficient, he can run crying to his manager. And explain to his manager that my allocator hurt his feelings.

it would be more like "this library is incompatible with our chosen allocation system"

“This library is not compatible with your ‘interesting’ ideas how allocation should work. That’s a ‘you’ problem, not a ‘me’ problem”.

Ok you feel a need to expose a compile-time constant-valued size expression for the opaque structure.
Assuming that this structure's implementation is not composed entirely of chars the size of the structure will probably be architecture-dependant.
So that means either you need to ship a different public header with each architecture of the library  or to combine all the available architectures into a single header.
These approaches while somewhat complicated can performed using your C compiler or cross compiler to build a program (or programs) that generate the public header as part of your library build process (and then execute those programs to make the header)
If you can settle instead for a link-time constant value then the public header file no longer needs to hold size of the structure. I feel that it must be possible to get the size of the structure into a library symbol but can't think of the exact incantation right now.
If making it run_time constant is enough then something like
private.c
public const size_t structsize = sizeof ( private_struct );

public.h
extern const size_t structsize

will get you there.

In general, you'd also need to consider any alignment restrictions on the actual struct.  An identically-sized array of char would likely not have such an alignment restriction.

sizeof() alreasy bakes in slack space for alignment. To me an array a char is "composed entirely of chars"

sizeof() returns a value - it implies no alignment whatsoever.  What's the alignment of char a[ structsize ]; (assuming the compiler supports VLAs)?

I guess you're stuck with using alloca() if you want it on the stack.

C11 has the specifier _Alignas ( constant-expression ):  "The constant expression shall be an integer constant expression. It shall evaluate to a valid fundamental alignment, or to a valid extended alignment supported by the implementation in the context in which it appears, or to zero."  Unfortunately:  "An alignment attribute shall not be specified in a declaration of a typedef..."  So typdef _Alignas(16) char myOpaqueType[48]; seems to be out, but struct _Alignas(16) myOpaqueType { char buf[48] }; seems OK.

size_t context_size = sha_context_size();
char sha_context[context_size]; // C99
char * sha_context = alloca(context_size); // other versions
sha_context_init(sha_context);

error handling is omitted

@freakish, I swear I've posted before I've seen your comment :)

Interestingly, the SHA-256 implementation I did not long ago did have a function call that returns the size of the working context, as well as IUF subroutine pointers. I even made macro version of the said function so that SHA-256 context can be allocated statically.

If malloc() performance is critical, we are likely working in a very lean environment (embedded). They often come without threading support and do not need a lot of concurrency. Therefore we can provide two APIs - to handle non-concurrent processing without allocations and to handle concurrent processing with allocations:
opaque_sha_context * sha_context = sha_init(NULL, NULL); // allocation disabled, non-concurrent, returns statically preallocated area
if (!sha_context) {
    sha_context = sha_init(malloc, free); // concurrent implementation, uses malloc
}
sha_process(sha_context, file);
sha_free(sha_context); // either frees memory, or allows next use of a statically preallocated area

I've never done or seen such API in practice
